# Function $f(x)$ is differentiable over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=5$ and $f(x)<5$ for $\forall x \neq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If function  $f(x)$ is differentiable $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=5$ and $f(x)<5$ for $\forall x \neq 1$ Then?

$1). f(x)$ is monotonically increasing

$2). f(x)$ is bounded

$3). f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing

$4). f(x)$ is not monotonic

**solution i tried**
-The condition is $f(x)$ is differentiable so it implies that $f(x)$ is continious on whole $\mathbb{R}$
after a long hour of thinking i create a function $\displaystyle \frac{5}{1+(1-x)^2}$ which is $5$ at $x=1$ and also $f(x)<5 \;\forall\; x\neq 1$ ,from this function one thing is clear that function is not monotonic. So we can eliminate options $1$ and $3$ but what about $2$ and $4$ ,because this above function satisfies both the conditions.what can i say about this function.Please provide me a hint.

Thank you

Comment: Try considering the function $f(x) = 5 - (1 - x)^2$

Comment: @Sten Thank you ,Now i got it.